# load jni so files from system/lib64 fail

Tags: android

I have a app which call jni libraries in Android13, since the libraries called by multiple app, so I wish to put the jni so files at `/system/product/lib64` folder to save sapce.

Unfortunately, it not work!

```
10-30 20:14:57.214  6118  6118 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/product/lib64/libanative.so" needed or dlopened by "/apex/com.android.art/lib64/libnativeloader.so" is not accessible for the namespace "classloader-namespace"
```

Any ideas to fix it?